# Let $S_1 \leq S_2 \leq..$ be a strictly increasing chain of simple subgroups of a group $G$. Show that $\cup_i S_i$ is a simple subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_1 \leq S_2 \leq..$ be a strictly increasing chain of simple subgroups of a group $G$. Show that $\cup_i S_i$ is a simple subgroup of $G$

So I understand that how to show that $\cup_i S_i \leq G$... I'm struggling to show that $\cup_i S_i$ is simple.

If $L \leq \cup_i S_i$ and $L \leq S_j$ for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$, then $L$ must not be normal because $S_j$ is trivial. But i'm not sure how to deal with cases $L \leq \cup_i S_i$ and $L \cap S_j \neq 0$ $\forall j$. Can it be shown that in this case $L = \cup_i S_i$?

Comment: Show that if $L\triangleleft \cup S_i$, then $L\cap S_j\triangleleft S_j$ for each $j$. Conclude that $L\cap S_j=S_j$ or $L\cap S_j = \{e\}$ for each $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\bigcup\limits_i {{S_i}} $. Assume that there exist a normal subgroup $N \triangleleft S$, then $N \cap {S_i} \triangleleft {S_i}$ for all i. But $S_i$ are simple, so $N \cap {S_i} = \{ 1\} $ or $N \cap {S_i} = \{ S_i\} $ i.e. $S_i \le N$. Now $N = N \cap S = N \cap \bigcup\limits_i {{S_i}}  = \bigcup\limits_i {(N \cap {S_i})} $, thus it is imposible that $N \cap {S_i} = \{ 1\} $ for all i or $S_i \le N$ for all i. This means that there exist $j$ and $k$ such that $S_k \le N$ and $S_j \cap N={1}$. Now we compare $S_i$ and $S_k$ to see a contradiction. If $j \le k$, then $S_j \le S_k$ and $S_j \cap N={1}$ and $S_k \le N$, a contradiction. If $k \le j$, doing similar leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Just a minor observation: You need to assume that $N$ is a *proper, non-trivial* normal subgroup of $S$. This assumption is used in the claim which starts " thus it is imposible that...".

Comment: Good luck on qualifiers bro!!!

Comment: Oh, Hakuna Matata, thank you, but how can you know that I am gonna take qualifiers?